# Correct way to access the scope from a directive on multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, mean-stack

I have a directive named add-tags than I am planning to use in different places of the app, I am using it to add tags to an array then save from the main ctrl, then the user can edit the list when previewing from a different view/ctrl (modal), on main page I have:

```
<add-tags tags="tags"></add-tags>
```

and my directive is set up as follow:

```
'use strict';

        angular.module('theApp')
            .directive('addTags', function() {
                return {
                    templateUrl: 'components/add-tags/add-tags.html',
                    //restrict: 'EA',
                    scope: {
                       tags:'='
                     },
                    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
                    } //link
                };
            });
```

From the edit controller, how can access the previous tags data? when I do,

```
<add-tags tags="workDetails.tags"></add-tags>
```

the entire data from is gone from the scope, but when I do:

```
<span ng-repeat="x in workDetails.tags">
           <h1>{{x.name}}</h1>
        </span>
```

I can see the list of tags, any help will be appreciated :)

I am adding the add-tags.html example:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags" class="text-center new-item">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.name">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button 
                       type="button" 
                       class="btn btn-default"
                       ng-click="deleteTag($index)">
                       Delete
                    </button>
                </span> <!-- /.input-group-btn -->
            </div> <!-- /.input-group -->
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="tags.length == tags_max">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter tag:" ng-model="tag">
        </div> 

        <!-- /.form-group -->
        <button 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-primary center-block"
            ng-disabled="tags.length == tags_max"
            ng-class="{ 'btn-danger': tags.length == tags_max}"
            ng-click="addTag()">
            Add tag
        </button>

        <hr>
```

Comment: Because your directive is doing nothing with the scope.tags it's given?  Share your add-tags.html template.

Comment: @RamblinRose I added the add-tag.html template

Comment: I did this a while ago, hope it helps http://codepen.io/comakai/pen/epMBOE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you've given.  However - unless I am missing some information - is it possible you're assuming that your "workDetails" object should be available everywhere?  The only way I could get your scenario to work is by adding a "workDetailsService" that holds the tag state.

[Here's a working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tzL6QhwVrCqESwQOAj3H?p=preview) of the code bits you provided, but with a workDetailsService added to maintain state and some routing.

Basically I added a service to maintain the tags:

```
theApp.factory('workDetailsService', function() {
  return {
    tags: [{
      name: "Tag 1"
    }, {
      name: "Tag 2"
    }, {
      name: "Tag 3"
    }]
  }
});
```

And injected that service into two directives, "listTags" and "editTags":

```
theApp.directive('editTags', ['workDetailsService', function(workDetailsService) {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/edit-tags.html',
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {

      $scope.tags_max = 4;
      $scope.tags = workDetailsService.tags;

      $scope.addTag = function() {
        workDetailsService.tags.push({
          name: $scope.tag
        })
      }
      $scope.deleteTag = function(index) {
        workDetailsService.tags.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  };
}]);

theApp.directive('listTags', ['workDetailsService', function(workDetailsService) {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/list-tags.html',
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
      $scope.tags = workDetailsService.tags;
    }
  };
}]);
```

This way you have your tags state in one place, and the directives wrap the tags up instead of controllers so you can reuse everywhere.